# Thunderbird Add-Ons Development basics

Tags: javascript, mozilla, thunderbird-addon

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Thunderbird/Creating_a_Custom_Column

but show the sender's email address in the new column instead of Reply-To value.

I tried everything I can think of and nothing works.

```
getCellText:         function(row, col) { 

    var hdr = gDBView.getMsgHdrAt( row ); 

    return hdr.getStringProperty( "author" ); 
}
```

how can I get a list of the available properties from MsgHdr ?  I managed to find properties like "replyTo", "subject", and even "sender" which gives me the display name of the sender, but I am looking for the email address of the sender.

also, how can I debug this in a javascript debugger?  I installed Venkman but I can't, for example, get a reference to gDBView in the Interactive Session.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever comes after me in search of this.  Run the following in Thunderbird's Error Console (Add On):

```
var hdr=top.opener.gFolderDisplay.selectedMessage; var e=hdr.propertyEnumerator; while ( e.hasMore() ) { var key=e.getNext(); Application.console.log("\tproperty: " + key + "\t" + hdr.getProperty( key ) ); }
```